# how to programmatically add ngBootstrap popover to element?

Tags: javascript, angular, fullcalendar, ng-bootstrap, fullcalendar-4

I am currently working on a calendar in my angular v8 application.

This is the plugin I use: https://fullcalendar.io

this is the component which I include in my html template:

```
    <full-calendar
        defaultView="dayGridMonth"
        [editable]="true"
        [eventLimit]="5"
        [nowIndicator]="true"
        [slotLabelFormat]="timeFormat"
        [eventTimeFormat]="timeFormat"
        [eventClassName]="'fc-event-brand'"
        [minTime]="'08:00:00'"
        [maxTime]="'24:00:00'"
        [header]="{
          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'dayGridMonth, timeGridWeek, timeGridDay, listWeek'
        }"
        [plugins]="calendarPlugins"
        [events]="calendarEvents"
        (eventMouseEnter)="showPopover($event)"
        (eventMouseLeave)="hidePopover($event)"
        (eventRender)="renderTooltip($event)"></full-calendar>
```

But how can I add a ngBootstrap popover or tooltip to an element?

this is the renderTooltip():

```
renderTooltip(event) {
    // bind ngBootstrap tooltip or popover to $event.el
}
```

Comment: you can see the demo here : [link](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-tooltip-demo) search for 'tooltip' in page source and you will see the implementation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would create one simple component which is basically just a popover wrapper:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <div class="fc-content" [ngbPopover]="template" container="body" triggers="manual">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class PopoverWrapperComponent {
  template: TemplateRef<any>;

  @ViewChild(NgbPopover, { static: true }) popover: NgbPopover;
}
```

- `template` property will be passed from our main component so we can create any template we want
- we also hold of `NgbPopover` instance so we can use `popover.open(context)` later.

Also make sure you've added this component to `entryComponents` array of your `NgModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FullCalendarModule, NgbPopoverModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, PopoverWrapperComponent ],
  entryComponents: [PopoverWrapperComponent],
                              \/
                           like this
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Now we're going to dynamically render this component into `$event.el` element and project child nodes in `ng-content`.

```
import { Component, ComponentRef,
 TemplateRef, ViewChild, ComponentFactoryResolver, 
 Injector, ApplicationRef } from '@angular/core';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import { NgbPopover } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  calendarPlugins = [dayGridPlugin];

  calendarEvents = [
    { title: 'event 1', date: '2019-08-09', customProp1: 'customProp1', customProp2: 'customProp2' },
    { title: 'event 2', date: '2019-08-12', customProp1: 'customProp3', customProp2: 'customProp4' }
  ];

  @ViewChild('popoverTmpl', { static: true }) popoverTmpl: TemplateRef<any>;

  popoversMap = new Map<any, ComponentRef<PopoverWrapperComponent>>();

  popoverFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(PopoverWrapperComponent);

  constructor(
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, 
    private injector: Injector,
    private appRef: ApplicationRef) {
  }

  renderTooltip(event) {
    const projectableNodes = Array.from(event.el.childNodes)

    const compRef = this.popoverFactory.create(this.injector, [projectableNodes], event.el);
    compRef.instance.template = this.popoverTmpl;

    this.appRef.attachView(compRef.hostView);
    this.popoversMap.set(event.el, compRef);
  }

  destroyTooltip(event) {
    const popover = this.popoversMap.get(event.el); 
    if (popover) {
      this.appRef.detachView(popover.hostView);
      popover.destroy();
      this.popoversMap.delete(event.el);
    }
  }

  showPopover(event) {
    const popover = this.popoversMap.get(event.el);
    if (popover) {
      popover.instance.popover.open({ event: event.event });
    }
  }

  hidePopover(event) {
    const popover = this.popoversMap.get(event.el);
    if (popover) {
      popover.instance.popover.close();
    }
  }
}
```

The key part here is how we're rendering component [dynamically with projectable nodes](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactory#create):

```
renderTooltip(event) {
  const projectableNodes = Array.from(event.el.childNodes)

  const compRef = this.popoverFactory.create(this.injector, [projectableNodes], event.el);
  compRef.instance.template = this.popoverTmpl;

  this.appRef.attachView(compRef.hostView)
  this.popoversMap.set(event.el, compRef)
}
```

Rendered dynamically component has no relation to the Angular change detection tree so we have to add its view to `ApplicationRef` views so change detection should work there.

Make sure you've subscribed to the following event in your template:

```
(eventRender)="renderTooltip($event)"
(eventDestroy)="destroyTooltip($event)"
(eventMouseEnter)="showPopover($event)"
(eventMouseLeave)="hidePopover($event)"
```

You should also define template for popover, i.e.:

```
<ng-template #popoverTmpl let-event="event">
  <h6>{{ event.title }}</h6>
  <div>
    <p>{{ event.extendedProps.customProp1 }}</p>
    <p>{{ event.extendedProps.customProp2 }}</p>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z8cwaq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

**[Stackblitz Example with @fullcalendar/angular/5.5.0](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3quqrn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: @yurzui,  clap,clap,clap

Comment: Okay there is a problem with this solution - if you use interactionPlugin it breaks 
 resizing functionality, which can be fixed by removing `fc-content` class from `PopoverWrapperComponent`. It adds two nested `fc-content` divs, instead of one. Otherwise it works perfect, thank you!

Comment: Great solution, thumbs up!
The conflicting 'fc-event' class issue can be resolved in providing your own css class with the popover property popoverClass.
So in the PopoverWrapperComponent template could be like:
<div [ngbPopover]="template" container="body" triggers="manual" popoverClass="fc-event_popover">
   <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>

Comment: The StackBlitz example appears to be broken

Comment: @DanielFlippance No, you didn't see anything there because it used old dates. I updated it to use current days https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z8cwaq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Can you update your code for fullcalendar 5.x?

Comment: @tala9999 I added it to my answer. You can check that out

Comment: @yurzui. Thanks for quick response. It works great until I hook `eventContent:this.renderEventContent`, then the popover shows at incorrect position, sometimes at the top-left corner. Any ideas? `renderEventContent(arg) {return 'test';}`

Comment: Very nice solution, a shame it has to be so complicated. In Angular 13, `ComponentFactoryResolver` is deprecated. Is there a future-proof alternative?

Comment: After some investigation, this solutions unfortunately leads to new problems: The text in events in grid view will print outside the box if long (overflow issue) and the events in the list view will collapse in an odd way.